# Thingsboard - Widget custom action - Link to another dashboard

Tags: hyperlink, action, dashboard, thingsboard

I have an overview dashboard with a map and many markers for the machines. Every machine has its own dashboard. Since i can not work with states because every machine has different parameters, i need to link the existing dashboards by the custom action function.

All dashboards are named the same as the devices so it should be possible to link them trough entitiyName. But there is no documentation how to get the dashboard name with JavaScript in the custom action and how then open the dashboard instead of a state.

I hope somebody can help. Thanks!

Comment: Why do you use seperate dashboards instead of states? My solution to something similar was to use the device attributes to save a custom device type and decide which detail-page (dashboard-state) to show based on that type info.

Comment: Sounds good! I definitly will try that and see how practical that would be. Thanks!
But it would be great to know if the other solution is possible too.

Comment: At least at my end it is practical, because we can reuse detail-pages for devices of the same type. Also, the user only has access to that single dashboard (no need to assign users to all detail-dashboards, user gets simpler UI without dashboard-selection). However, linking to a dashboard should work by just placing a link on the page `<a href="/dashboards/{DASHBOARD_id}">Dashboard Link</a>`. I'm not sure how to get the dashboard id. Maybe the [REST-api (getUserDashboards)](https://cloud.thingsboard.io/swagger-ui.html#!/dashboard-controller/getUserDashboardsUsingGET) can help you out.

Comment: Also you can read the thingsboard code to check out how existing dashboard links are implemented.

Comment: I think I go with your solution first, since all you said makes sense! Thank you! 
I already tried to find the solution in the repository, but it's not clear to me how to adapt it to the "custom action" field and how it plays together with the rest of the application. I could work trough it to understand how TB was designed, but thats not my priority now ;-)

Comment: Sure, with the API a dynamic generation of links could work. But I don't know if and how it's possible to work with the api in the "Custom action" field.